# get and send data to server is slow on wifi, fast on mobile internet.

Tags: android, android-asynctask, multipartentity

I have an async task which fetches a file from my server. it takes long before it starts but when it starts it is fast. on mobile its is done in about 5 seconds while on wifi i can wait for 40seconds+.

this is the asynctask:
public class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask {
@Override

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            // in background
            for (int i = 0; i < selectedWidgets.size(); i++) {
                saveWidget(selectedWidgets.get(i));
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

so it starts  savewidget.
savewidget = download file and store it local

here is the savewidget:

```
public void saveWidget(int widgetnumber) {
        try {
            // set location and name
            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "widgets");
            jsonPath = root.getAbsolutePath() + "/widget";

            File gpxfile = new File(root, "widget" + widgetnumber + ".txt");

            if (!gpxfile.exists()) {
                // if file doesn't excists, get it from the internet
                HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

                // add extra time to get it before error is thrown
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 0);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 0);
                HttpConnectionParams.setTcpNoDelay(httpParameters, true);
                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(
                        httpParameters);

                // set everyting to get it from the internet
                link = "http://somestuff/widget_id="
                        + widgetnumber;
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(link);
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                String result = null;
                BufferedReader reader = null;

                // set response
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                inputStream = entity.getContent();

                // read and save it
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,
                        "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                try {
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
                result = sb.toString();
                // code is in app
                if (!root.exists()) {
                    root.mkdirs();
                }
                // write it to new file
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
                writer.append(result);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

anyone who can explain why it needs so much time just to fetch a small over wifi and it goes fast over mobile internet? i'm kinda clueless atm.

is this a good way or is there a better?

maybe not bad to mention, at some point i use multipartentity in a service to send a video and data to the server. it works but just like this it is slow. once the first video is uploaded it goes fast.

multipartentity to send video:

```
public Void SendToServer(String aUrl, String file, String parameters,
            String uuid, String uploaded, int id) {
        // set extra settings for upload
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 0);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 0);
        HttpConnectionParams.setTcpNoDelay(params, true);
        params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.WAIT_FOR_CONTINUE,
                HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

        // add thes settings
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);

        // set uploadlocation
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(aUrl);
        try {
            jsonParameters = new JSONObject(parameters);
        } catch (JSONException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
            stopSelf();
        }

        // set video
        FileBody fb = new FileBody(new File(file));

        // get extra parameters from json and add them to entity
        try {
            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
                    HttpMultipartMode.STRICT);

            Iterator<String> iter = jsonParameters.keys();
            // loop as long as there are keys
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                String key = iter.next();
                try {
                    value = jsonParameters.get(key);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // Something went wrong!
                    stopSelf();
                }
                // add them
                entity.addPart(key, new StringBody(value.toString()));

            }
            // continue to add data to entity
            entity.addPart("widget_uuid", new StringBody(uuid));
            entity.addPart("widget_uploaded", new StringBody(uploaded));
            entity.addPart("file", fb);
            httpPost.setEntity(entity);

            // get response from server
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            try {
                // get statuscode from server
                HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
                String serverRespons = "";
                if (serverRespons != null) {
                    serverRespons = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
                }

                serverRespons = serverRespons.substring(
                        serverRespons.indexOf("(") + 1,
                        serverRespons.indexOf(")"));

                try {
                    jsonServerRespons = new JSONObject(serverRespons);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                }

                try {
                    statusServerRespons = jsonServerRespons.getString("status");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Log.i("test", statusServerRespons);
                // delete successfully sended video's
                if (statusServerRespons.equalsIgnoreCase("ok")) {
                    vds.deleteTitle(id);
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
                // Something went wrong!
                stopSelf();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // Something went wrong!
                stopSelf();
            }
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Something went wrong!
            stopSelf();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you done a speedtest? The wifi should be faster, but maybe it's having a bad day.

Comment: i have this problem since i builded the app ^^ over a month ago. and tested on multiple locations (work, home, friends,...) speedtest= 20ping 16.45mbs upload 4.58mbs so nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @Django Steemans Found your problem yet?

Comment: no I didn't found a solution. It was a job I had as internship so I did this a long time ago and am not really searching anymore. Anyone who has a solution feel free to answer because I'm still curious.